# Sync data from AWS s3 to localstack s3

Tags: amazon-web-services

I have a local s3 service running in my local system using localStack. I want to copy files from my AWS s3 location to my local s3 server bucket. I am not finding any way to connect or sync AWS s3 to remote bucket or remote s3 server(i.e my local s3 server). Any suggestion would be very helpful.

One way that I figured out is very tedious. I can use 'aws sync' and copy the file to my local system(C: or D:) and then copy the data from local system to the local s3 server. But I need some other efficient solution.

Comment: We don't have the functionality in place yet, but you can easily view your data both locally and on AWS using Commandeer getcommandeer.com We do plan on adding this ability soon, so pretty cool to see a request like this out in the wild.

Comment: @WallMobile Thanks for your response. VIewing data is pretty easy. If I want to use something like LocalStack(Local AWS Server) for my testing purpose, I should have the leverage to sync my s3 bucket to my local s3 bucket. Good to know you are planning to add this soon. If it will be possible please keep me posted :)